# DCF77 decoder vs. noisy signal

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, arduino, signal-processing, dcf77

I have almost completed my open source DCF77 decoder project. It all started out when I noticed that the standard (Arduino) DCF77 libraries perform very poorly on noisy signals. Especially I was never able to get the time out of the decoders when the antenna was close to the computer or when my washing machine was running.

My first approach was to add a (digital) exponential filter + trigger to the incoming signal.

Although this improved the situation significantly, it was still not really good. Then I started to read some standard books on digital signal processing and especially the original works of Claude Elwood Shannon. My conclusion was that the proper approach would be to not "decode" the signal at all because it is (except for leap seconds) completely known a priori. Instead it would be more appropriate to match the received data to a locally synthesized signal and just determine the proper phase. This in turn would reduce the effective bandwidth by some orders of magnitude and thus reduce the noise significantly.

Phase detection implies the need for fast convolution. The standard approach for efficient convolution is of course the fast Fourier transform. However I am implementing for the Arduino / Atmega 328. Thus I have only 2k RAM. So instead of the straightforward approach with FFT, I started stacking matched phase locked loop filters. I documented the different project stages here:

- [First try: exponential filter](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/binary-clock/)
- [Start of the better apprach: phase lock to the signal / seconds ticks](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/phase-detection/)
- [Phase lock to the minutes](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/second-decoder/)
- [Decoding minute and hour data](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/decoding-time-data//)
- [Decoding the whole signal](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/decoding-everything/)
- [Adding a local clock to deal with signal loss](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/local-clock/)
- [Using local synthesized signal for faster lock reacquisition after signal loss](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/the-clock/)

I searched the internet quite extensively and found no similar approach. Still I wonder if there are similar (and maybe better) implementations. Or if there exist research on this kind of signal reconstruction.

What I am not searching for: designing optimized codes for getting close to the Shannon limit. I am also not searching for information on the superimposed PRNG code on DCF77. I also do not need hints on "matched filters" as my current implementation is an approximation of a matched filter. Specific hints on Viterbi Decoders or Trellis approaches are not what I am searching for - unless they address the issue of tight CPU and RAM constraints.

What I am searching for: are there any descriptions / implementations of other non-trivial algorithms for decoding signals like DCF77, with **limited CPU and RAM** in the presence of significant noise? Maybe in some books or papers from the pre internet era?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but have you considered replacing the low-pass filter and trigger with the [Viterbi algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) on a two-state Markov chain?

Comment: This seems like the most over-engineered clock I have ever seen, but I like it a lot. Must have been a fun project. Have to read through all your blog entries when I have more time. The sort of convolution with a predicted waveform seems close to an optimal solution. Did you read up on [Kalman filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)? This has some similarities with what you did, the idea is roughly to simulate the system you observe, and then compare the simulated measurements with the real measurements to update the state of your model based on the difference.

Comment: With regard to the Viterbi algorithm and Kamlman filtering you are right. These are possible routes of investigation. However I did not try them due to the tight memory and CPU constraints. If someone has tried this on a such a weak CPU I would be eager to learn about the implementations.

With regard to the over engineering: there is some strange satisfaction in it. "Everything worth doing is worth overdoing ;)"

The convolution approach with the fully know signal is also known as "optimal filter". The only issue is that due to the memory constraints I can only approximate it.

Comment: On second thought, I am not sure if Kalman filtering is appropriate, there you usually measure some continuous physical parameter and not something that contains some digital modulation. It might be more interesting to study how GPS receivers work. They do some sort of convolution and typically contain a small microprocessor. The main difference is that they use a real PRN generator, while in your case you locally reconstruct the timing signal, which is slightly less random. The convolution part should be similar.

Comment: Two-state Viterbi shouldn't be appreciably more resource-intensive than the low-pass + trigger.

Comment: I do not understand how Two-state Viterbi would any improvements. The recurrence implies that you need significantly more states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to matched filters by Ollie B. is not what I was asking for. I already covered this before in my blog.

However by now I received a very good hint by private mail. There exists a paper ["Performance Analysis and
Receiver Architectures of DCF77 Radio-Controlled Clocks"](http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/417284/Engeler_DCF77.pdf) by Daniel Engeler. This is the kind of stuff I am searching for.

With further searches starting from the Engeler paper I found the following German patents [DE3733966A1 - Anordnung zum Empfang stark gestoerter Signale des Senders dcf-77](https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/pat/PatSchrifteneinsicht?docId=DE3733966A1) and [DE4219417C2 - Schmalbandempfänger für Datensignale](https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/pat/PatSchrifteneinsicht?docId=DE4219417C2).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a chip matched filter to perform your convolution?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter

They are almost trivially easy to implement, as each chip / bit period can be implemented as a n add subtract delay line ( use a circular buffer )

A simple one for a square wave (will also work, but less optimal with other waveforms) of unknown sequence (but known frequency) can be implemented something like this:

```c
// Filter class
template <int samples_per_bit>
class matchedFilter(
   public:
      // constructor
      matchedFilter() : acc(0) {};

      // destructor
      ~matchedFilter() {};

      int filterInput(int next_sample){
        int temp;
        temp = sample_buffer.insert(nextSample);
        temp -= next_sample;
        temp -= result_buffer.insert(temp);
        return temp;
      };

   private:
     int acc;
     CircularBuffer<samples_per_bit> sample_buffer;
     CircularBuffer<samples_per_bit> result_buffer;
);

// Circular buffer
template <int length>
class CircularBuffer(
   public:
      // constructor
      CircularBuffer() : element(0) {
         buffer.fill(0);
      };
      // destructor
      ~CircularBuffer(){};

      int insert(int new_element){
        int temp;
        temp = array[element_pos];
        array[element_pos] = new_element;
        element_pos += 1;
        if (element_pos == length){
           element_pos = 0;
        };
        return temp;
      }

   private:
      std::array<int, length> buffer;
      int element_pos;
);
```

As you can see, resource wise, this is relatively trivial. It there is a specific waveform you're after, you can cascade these together to give a longer correlation.

Comment: I am already implementing a recursive stack of matched filters. I am aware of this approach. However the straight forward approach you are suggesting fails for the tight memory constraints. With 2k your approach would allow to sample for at most 1000s which would be worse than what I am currently able to do.

Comment: I'm interested in how you'd build a matched filter to operate on more than 1000s without storing 1000s worth of data. Also your SNR must be awful if you require 1000s. That's a 40dB gain isn't it?

Comment: The whole point of the experiment was to push SNR as far as possible. For the details read my blog. I have documented everything. The key is that the begin of the data is always at the begin of the second. So I can match this and then recursively the rest. However I would say that 1000s is a digital gain of 30 dB instead of 40.

Comment: However since I can only approximate a matched filter I do not get 30dB. But I can sample longer and thus get a better gain.