# Moving mean square error between 2 arrays, 'valid', where they fully overlap

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, convolution

I have a noisy square signal which looks like this:

[image: square signal]

The amplitude is known. To match the complete square, I can create a pattern of the square and apply `np.correlate` to find where the signal and the pattern maximally overlap. I wanted to apply a similar approach to find the edge, try to correlate with the 2 patterns below:

[image: pattern]

As the correlation is nothing more than a convolution, this doesn't work. Half the pattern is equal to `0`, and the convolution of this half will return `0` no matter the position on the signal; while the other half is equal to `-X` with `X` the amplitude. This second half convoluted with the signal will be maximal when the signal amplitude is maximal. On the signal plot, you can observe that the square is not perfect and that the beginning has a slightly larger amplitude. Basically, both correlation leads to a match on the beginning of the square, where the convolution is maximal. The ramp up (end of the square) is not detected.

To avoid this problem, I would like to use a different operation. As I do know the amplitude of the square signal, I can generate a pattern with the correct amplitude, in this case about `-0.3`. Thus, I would like to take the pattern and slide it across the signal. At each step, I would compute the mean square error and my pattern would match with the signal at the position where the mean square error is minimized. Moreover, I would like to use the same type of setting as for a convolution, 'valid', where the operation is performed only when the 2 arrays fully overlap.

**Do you know of an other method; and/or which function, methods I should use?** I couldn't find a all-in-one function line `np.convolve` or `np.correlate`.

EDIT: Since I couldn't find a pre-coded function in a library, I've coded mine with a while loop. It's pretty inefficient... It's up [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248184/moving-mean-square-error-between-2-arrays-valid-where-they-fully-overlap) on codereview for upgrades.

Comment: share your code attempt with minimum reproducible example

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma There is no point in sharing the convolution of array 1 with array 2. It's one line of code than anyone with knowledge about this has. I'm not either willing to code by hand a complete function doing a moving mean square error operation, as the all point of the question is to ask if someone knows of a library (numpy, scipy, ...) with this operation pre-coded.

Comment: you can use comparison to find out when signal changes

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma I guess what you are referring to is "If the signal goes below a threshold, then the square started". Not accurate enough. The vertical ramp is not instantaneous, depends on the amplitude of the signal, ... That's why I'm working towards something a little more advanced than a threshold, which value you would have to imperfectly choose.

Comment: That's why, if you could provide minimum reproducible example, then we could try on something

Comment: @Mathieu may be converting `signal` into `frequency` domain and applying some `filters` can be helpfull

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde So, my knowledge in signal processing isn't advance. I didn't try to first convert to frequency domain, but I did try the following: Butterworth; bessel; convolution with hannning, hamming, Bartlett, Blackman window; moving median filtering. Aside from the non-linear moving median, the others lead to a bad trade-off between noise removal and sharpness of the edge (which contains high frequency). I usually end up smoothing the edge, thus leading to a worst measure of the timing at which it occurs.

Comment: Well, I have an idea, I haven't tested it yet. Since you have a square signal, its Fourier transfrom is a [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function), which will be symmetric around 0. From the minimums of that sinc function you should be able to retrieve the period the the square signal: the distance of the two closest minimal points is `2/T` where T is the period of your square signal.

Comment: @PéterLeéh I'm not sure how to implement this, especially as I have cropped the signal to a nice position around the square. There is also some larger overshoot, some which are larger than the square, outside of this cropped window. Nonetheless, this idea seems very interesting and I will try to implement it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that convolving/correlating your signal with a step function is still pretty close to the optimal solution, since this is similar to [matched filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter), which can be proven to be optimal (under certain conditions, noise likely needs to be Gaussian).

The only issue you have is that your template (the step function) contains a DC part. Removing this, will give you the result you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# simulate the signal
signal = np.zeros(4000)
signal[200:-400] = -0.3
signal += 0.005 * np.random.randn(*signal.shape)

plt.plot(signal)
plt.title('Simulated signal')
plt.show()


# convolve with template with non-zero DC
templ = np.zeros(200)
templ[100:] = 1  # step from 0 to 1
plt.plot(np.convolve(signal, templ))
plt.title('Convolution with template with DC component')
plt.show()

# convolve with template without DC
templ_ac = templ - templ.mean()  # step from -0.5 to +0.5
plt.plot(np.convolve(signal, templ_ac))
plt.title('Convolution with template without DC component')
plt.show()
```

Results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The way to understand this is that `convolve(signal, template) = convolve(signal, template_DC) + convolve(signal, template_AC)`, where `template_DC = mean(template)` and `template_AC = template - template_DC`. The first part is the convoltion of the signal with a flat template, which  is just a smoothed version of your signal. The second part is the 'edge detection' signal you want. If you do not subtract the AC part of the template, the uninteresting first part dominates the interesting part.

Note that the scaling of the template is not important, the step in the template doesn't have to be 0.3. This will just cause a scale factor in the end result. Also note that this method does not depend on the exact value of the step, so a larger step in your signal will cause a large effect in the edge detection.

If you know that the step is always exactly 0.3, and you want to be insensitive to steps of different amplitude, you could do some sort of least square fitting of the signal with the template, for every possible shift of the templatate, and only trigger a detection of an edge if the residual is small enough. This will be slow, but might give better rejection of steps with the wrong amplitude.

Comment: Thank you for your instructive input. I didn't think about it as AC/DC components, but I reached the same conclusion when thinking about what the convolution was doing, and ended up using a +1/-1. What you mention in your last paragraph looks like what I was trying to achieve and called a "moving window mean square error". I'm surprised I couldn't find a library implementation of this as I expect it would yield better results than the convolution when the signal's amplitude is small and the edge/ramp is not as sharp as on the plot above. Yet, I'm not sure, and that's why I wanted to test both.

Comment: One more aspect, if I would design a template which is the complete square, the DC would still be negative; and yet the convolution would work just fine and would be maximized when the template overlaps the signal completely. What do you make of this? This animation shows it clearly: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produit_de_convolution#/media/Fichier:Convolucion_Funcion_Pi.gif

Comment: You don't have to subtract the DC part, it will just give an offset in the resulting convolution. Just note that also the signal could have a DC part, so you have `conv(s,t) = conv(s_DC, t_DC) + conv(s_DC, t_AC) + conv(s_AC, t_DC) + conv(s_AC, t_AC)`, which should explain the complete result. You can remove the DC part or do high-pass filtering on either the signal or the template before the convolution as needed.

Comment: What got me interested in these kind of convolution techniques for detecting rectangular signals is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18029614) about detecting very weak DCF77 radio clock signals. Especially the [second](https://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/phase-detection/) of the linked blog posts talks a lot about convolution.